# Loading KRPano inside Cordova Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, krpano

I have created a Phonegap project using Cordova CLI and my index.html page contains a 360VR image to be watched using KRPano.
Everything works well except that, from time to time, the page gets automatically reloaded. The Debugger shows that this method in CDVWebViewDelegate.m gets called continuously

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    VerboseLog(@"webView didFinishLoad (before). state=%d loadCount=%d", _state, _loadCount);
    BOOL fireCallback = NO;
    switch (_state) {
        case STATE_IDLE:
            break;

        case STATE_WAITING_FOR_LOAD_START:
            NSLog(@"CDVWebViewDelegate: Unexpected didFinish while waiting for load start.");
            break;

        case STATE_WAITING_FOR_LOAD_FINISH:
            if (_loadCount == 1) {
                fireCallback = YES;
                _state = STATE_IDLE;
            }
            _loadCount -= 1;
            break;

        case STATE_IOS5_POLLING_FOR_LOAD_START:
            [self pollForPageLoadStart:webView];
            break;

        case STATE_IOS5_POLLING_FOR_LOAD_FINISH:
            [self pollForPageLoadFinish:webView];
            break;
    }
    VerboseLog(@"webView didFinishLoad (after). state=%d loadCount=%d fireCallback=%d", _state, _loadCount, fireCallback);
    if (fireCallback && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webViewDidFinishLoad:)]) {
        [_delegate webViewDidFinishLoad:webView];
    }
}
```

to be precise the STATE_WAITING_FOR_LOAD_FINISH case is called.
In my Xcode debug logger I get this message multiple times

```
2016-01-12 00:07:23.922 MyApp[123:1345] Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
```

This produce an annoying effect on the 360VR experience. How can I prevent it?

Comment: can you provide the code you use? and the cordova CLI version/cordova ios version. Is the image stored online or inside the www folder?

Comment: at the moment I don't have this information but I can provide it later today. I can say the image is inside the www folder